# Prompt users to Upload Avatar on Registration

Tags: avatar

I saw a WP site that had users fill in their basic info and then it directed them to upload and Avatar. The site looked nice because most users had a picture even if they were'nt registered with Gravatar.

Is there a plugin for this local Avatar upload?

Comment: if you recall the site, you can check for relevant plugins by viewing the html source of the page. look for urls with /plugins/ in them

Comment: In the past when we needed to implement user avatar upload in our registration form, this tutorial on [adding File Upload Fields to a WordPress registration Form](https://profilepress.net/file-upload-fields-wordpress-registration-form/) was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin, it adds a upload avatar in the profile edit page.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/

Comment: Any experience to know if it can prompt them to upload during registration? My experience is that that's when it need to happen....or else the likely hood that they do it lessens greatly.

Comment: why dont you Use JQuery pop up or baloon tip to remind them to upload thier avatar during registration on registration page..
I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/ plugin to allow my users to edit their profile.. It create a separate page for the users to edit their profile from front end..

Comment: I like the idea, but not sure I'm clear on how that would look. Do you have an example? The site on Potty Training with Elimination Communication that I'm helping with http://ecsimplified.com has mostly mom's commenting without necessarily registering so in retrospect, I'm hoping to use a plugin that lets them choose from a few avatars right when they comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on this plugin [Profile Builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) that allows the users to upload their avatars on their registratration, and you can even build your own registration form.